# Is there an elegant way to refresh a given template with Iron Router?

Tags: meteor

Since my variables are not reactive and there are probably over 500 variables in my script, there is not feasable way I can make everything reactive right now.

So my question is, is there any way to make Iron Router refresh the current route/template when prompted? Right now, the only way I accomplish this is using `document.location.reload(true);`, but that is an ugly looking and very slow process.

Let's also say that I have a `{{> yield}}` element in my template: is there any way to just refresh that part without refreshing the entire page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to define a reactive variable (`Session` or `ReactiveVar`) and change the state of that variable. On your template, make an `if` wrapping the part you need to refresh. When you change the state, the part inside the `if` will be refreshed.

helpers:

```
h_checkToRefresh: function() {
   if (Session.get('count') > 0) return true;
   else return false;
}
```

template

```
{{#if h_checkToRefresh}}
   {{>yield}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for awaring me on this method. This is incredible. It opens up an entire window in more aesthetic web development. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: glad that it helps :)